# ImageMagick montage with logo

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am trying to create a Open Graph Image montage using between 1 and 3 images, with a logo overlaid over the final montage. I have this working with the following code - however, I have to generate the 1 to 3 image montage, then add the logo and generate a new image, then delete the first image. I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this - doing it all with one `exec` and not having to output two images and then delete one. Thanks for any advice.

```
if ($array_count == 1) {

        $w = 898;
        $h = 474;
        $t = '1x1';

    } else if ($array_count == 2) {

        $w = 449;
        $h = 474;
        $t = '2x2';

    } else if ($array_count == 3) {

        $w = 299;
        $h = 474;
        $t = '3x1';

    }

    $exe = " montage ";

    foreach ($photo_array as $p) {

        $exe .= " http://website.com/images/{$p} -thumbnail {$w}x{$h}^ -gravity center -extent {$w}x{$h} -geometry {$w}x{$h}+1+1 ";
    }

    $exe .= "-tile $t  ";

    $exe .= " poster1.jpg ";

    exec("$exe");

    exec(" convert  poster1.jpg  logo_overlay.png -gravity SouthEast -geometry +10+10 -composite poster2.jpg ");

    @unlink("poster1.jpg");

    $img_out = "poster2.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

In the light of the further information you have supplied, maybe this will help you see how to do it:

```
montage red.png lime.png blue.png cyan.png magenta.png yellow.png -geometry +0+0 -tile 3x2 miff:- | convert miff:- -gravity southeast logo.png -composite result.png
```

[image]

The logo is black and 50x50 whereas the other tiles are 100x100.

**Original Answer**

You can do it in a couple of ways - please take these as *schematic* answers rather than detailed down to the last pixel - but you should get the idea.

**Option 1**

You don't absolutely need to use `montage` to lay out images, you can use the `append` option to the `convert` command, whereby `-append` will place one image below another and `+append` will place one image to the right of the other. Then, as you are already using `convert` rather than `montage` you can composite your logo on top. So, your command will look like this:

```
convert \( image1.png -resize ... -extent ... \) \
        \( image2.png -resize ... -extent ... \) \
        +append                                  \
        \( image3.png -resize ... -extent ... \) \
        +append                                  \
        logo.png -gravity ... -composite result.png
```

**Option 2**

You can chain commands/images together, ideally by sending ImageMagick's `MIFF` file format down the pipe between the commands as that will preserve **all** image details, resolution and transparency. So you can do:

```
foreach image do
   convert image -resize ... -extent ... miff:-
done | montage -tile ... miff:-  miff:- | convert miff:- logo.png -composite result.png
```

Comment: Hi Mark. I tried the first option, however I also need it to work with up to 6 images. Tiled 3x3. For simplicity I just used 3 images in my example. I should have included all the code for up to 6 images tiled. So, the first option doesn't work for me with over 3 images, and I can't seem to work out the second option using `miff:-`. Could you possibly go into more detail on how I could implement option 2. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @Chris I have updated the answer - hopefully you can see how to do it now.

Comment: Excellent! Glad it worked out for you - good luck with your project! Remember questions are free, so come back with more later if you have any.